# Jquery tools tab speed

Tags: jquery, tabs, customization, slideshow

I am trying to control the speed of Jquery tools tab slider but can't quite get it to work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here...

I tried following code but that didn't work...

```
$(function() {
      $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

    // enable "cross-fading" effect
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
    // start from the beginning after the last tab

    rotate: true,

   // Autoplay doesn't work               
   autoPlay: true,  
   interval: 3000     

    // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
    }).slideshow();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shavindra/j7UcM/9/

So I tried this... which works but I can't control the interval

```
$(".slidetabs").data("slideshow").play({

      // interval configuration doesn't work    
      interval: 3000
     });
```

Documentation is here: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tabs/slideshow.html

JSfiddle links is here http://jsfiddle.net/shavindra/j7UcM/10/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to set this value like this:

```
$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div.slidebox", {

    // enable "cross-fading" effect
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
    //fadeOutSpeed: 200,

    // start from the beginning after the last tab
    rotate: true,
    autopause: false
// use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
}).slideshow(
    {autoplay: true, interval: 7000} // SET INTERVAL HERE
);
```